# How do I mock a method in another Service in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, mockito, junit5, spring-test

For context, I have 2 Service classes: `ValService` and `AppService`.

In `ValService` I have a method `validate`which calls a method in `AppService`:

`Character c = appService.sendToAPI(listOfString, stringId);`

The `sendToAPI` method calls an external API which returns a character.

Now, for testing `ValService`, how do I mock the method properly?

Answer (score 1):

IMHO I would test it like this.

```java
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class MyTest{
    @Mock
    AppService appService;
       
    @InjectMocks
    ValService valService;
      
    @Test
    void testValidation() {
        when(appService.sendToApi(any(), any())).thenReturn(getMeReturnChar());
           
        final var result = valService.validate("someData");

        assertThat(result).equalTo("myValidationSign");
    
    }
       
    private Character getMeReturnChar() {
        return 'testingCharacterOfYourChoice';
    }
}
```

But this is just rough example. I would need more information to help you further

Comment: i mocked FormValService with InjectMocks & AppValService with Mock.. but I'm a little confused.. do I not store the value in a variable like this? because my ValService validate method has check after calling that method,  if its equal to a certain value, if not its gonna throw error

Character c = when(appService.sendToAPI(anyList(), anyString())).thenReturn('A'); 

when i did this i got the following potential stubbing error :

appService.sendToApi([1], null); at Service class

has following stubbings with different arguments : appService.sendToApi(null, "") at Test Class

Comment: You do store the value but the value stored is the one you assign with `when(appService.sendToApi(any(), any())).thenReturn("character that you want to return for correct behavior")`. The rest is what the method of ValService is supposed to do. If you can provide some code I can assist better

Comment: edited the main post with code snippet.. i did 
```Character c = when(appService.sendToAPI(anyList(), anyString())).thenReturn('A'); ```

when i did this i got the following potential stubbing error :

appService.sendToApi([1], null); at Service class

has following stubbings with different arguments : appService.sendToApi(null, "") at Test Class